# Jquery:Draw Svg Line Dynamically While Dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I need to drag and drop cells from one table to another table where i am using it to develop foreign key mapping dynamically for the SQL table

Where the table also can be dragged as well inside the window, the mapping and drawing line between two tables are working perfectly

But when i bring the tables close to each other and when i move the tables further after the intersection of the tables the line is not drawing between the tables, i got where the issue is from but i cant figure out, how to draw the lines between the tables while intersection

So the issue is something like lines drawing from left to right but not right to left it is taking as intersection

```
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/2ecsjomz/embedded/result/
```

Here is the minimal example fiddle

```
Example : http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/2ecsjomz/4/
```

If you drag left drag box across the right drag box then line will not draw

This is just a demo, you can drag the primary key from table 1 and drop it in Table 2 works perfectly, But same as reverse will not draw the lines from table 2 to table 1 and also if you drag the table intersect with the table 2 the lines will not draw

**For better understanding:**

It is drawing perfectly
[image]

But when we bring the table near to another table line is not drawing
[image]

Comment: Please create a minimal demo showing the problem.

Comment: Ya sure paul i will show the minimal

Comment: sorry for late reply here is the minimal example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/2ecsjomz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was very simple to debug in the end.  Your problem starts here:

```
svgleft = Math.round(el1pos.left + el1W);
svgwidth = Math.round(el2pos.left - svgleft);
```

Once the boxes start overlapping, `svgwidth` becomes negative.  An SVG with a negative width is an error and the SVG will not be rendered.

You are either going to have to prevent the boxes from overlapping, or change the code to allow for 'right' being to the left of 'left'.

Comment: yaa width is getting 0 at that particular overlapping point , though if I populate the width , i am lagging in the curve , because the value of d is d="M0,327 C0,327 0,1 0,1" after overlapping, i am not well versed in SVG , i am just at kiddie level now, please help me

Comment: `svgleft` is calculated as the RHS of the "left" box `(el1pos.left + el1W)`.  `svgwidth` is calculated as the (X-pos-of-the-right-box - svgleft). Obviously this is wrong because you can't have elements in HTML that have negative widths.  So you could start by working out how to change the code so that svgleft is set to the actual leftmost X of those two points (RHS of "left", or LHS of "right"). Then you can calculate a non-negative width. That's trivial. Making the needed changes to the `<path>` is also very simple. There are many intros to SVG available. Or you can read the SVG spec.

Comment: Thank You Paul, Still there is a issue if we bring the boxes straight to each other after intersecting the line is overlapping the box, anyway i will solve it thank you paul